# How do birds eliminate oxygen free radicals

Tags: physiology, ornithology

Birds breathe in a lot. Do they produce a lot more of oxygen free radicals than mammals? And how do they cope with oxydative stress?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check on [google scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22birds%22+free+radicals+&btnG=)? There are a few papers there

Comment: “Birds breath a lot”! Me too.

Comment: @user438383 That is not scientific wording. better results from: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=avian+oxidative+free+radicals+&btnG=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some info on that here:
[Oxidative stress in ecology and evolution: lessons from avian studies](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1461-0248.2008.01246.x)

The article cites enzymes, antioxidants, brood size, serum analysis, body temperature, food types, membrane fatty acid composition, Vitamine E, carotenoids, and many other considerations. Perhaps you can read it and write an answer for us? Here is a summary:

> Possible explanations for the higher longevity of birds compared to their mammalian counterparts are that birds have (1) a lower ratio of oxygen radical production and oxygen consumption, (2) an exceptional cellular resistance to oxidative stress, (3) a lower mitochondrial and nuclear DNA oxidative damage, (4) a lower cell membrane unsaturation and (5) a slower life history for a given body size

[image]

Comment: thanks, this table is wonderful! I will try to find an answer, the article you shared seems to be more complete than what i had found so far. i will share my findings

Comment: take it with a big grain of salt "aging rate" is not a well defined thing. There are also big extraneous factors like mammals can run out of new teeth and starve becasue they can't feed, which is a common cause of death among mammals and nothing else. becasue mammals are basically the only group with limited numbers of teeth. and mammals can develop more in utero becasue of the advantage live birth has over eggs.